# Processing graph layer by layer

Tags: recursion, graph, tree

I have a task. Let's imagine we have a `tree`. We have a `trunk` and `branches`. Every branch has its own branches. Etc. To simplify the task we suppose that every branch has 2 branches on it. See the picture.

[image]

We want to address every branch, but we have to do it `layer by layer`. I mean at first we should address branches 1 and 2, after that 3,4,5,6, and so forth. Tried to make an algorythm for it, but anytime it ends up recursively going deeply: 1-3-7-8-4-9-10... Are there algorithms to process all the tree with unknown size without boilerplate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which goes through a graph layer by layer because it uses a queue to store its newly discovered nodes.